# Understand A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand when do I get a copy vs view when using .loc method to index the dataframe. Getting a view to me means any changes on view will be carried over to the original df. I expect using .loc gives me a copy.

In below example, I am indexing the df using the same method, but one gives me a copy, the other one gives me a view.
Can someone point out what I am missing?

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 1], [2, 4,1], [3,4,1]])
b = a.loc[:, 1:3]
b.loc[:, 'tag'] = 'test'  # this is a copy?
```

b seems to be a copy, since the 'tag' column shows only on b, not on a.

```
b
Out[70]: 
   1  2   tag
0  2  1  test
1  4  1  test
2  4  1  test
a
Out[71]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  1
1  2  4  1
2  3  4  1

c = a.loc[0:1, :]
c.loc[0, :] = 100 # why this is a view??
c
```

c seems to be a view of b. Because the changes on b is carried over to a.

```
Out[74]: c
     0    1    2
0  100  100  100
1    2    4    1
a
Out[75]: a
     0    1    2
0  100  100  100
1    2    4    1
2    3    4    1
```

Any why a.loc[:, 1:3] gives me 3 rows but a.loc[0:1, :] gives me 2 rows??

Comment: See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing "Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees), and therefore whether the __setitem__ will modify dfmi or a temporary object that gets thrown out immediately afterward. That’s what SettingWithCopy is warning you about!"

Comment: Also github site https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6149